# Does Output channel of conv2d to the next input shape of conv2d can be different?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

In the below code, you can see in, first nn.Sequential/conv2d, it has 512 output, but it next nn.Sequential/Convtranspose it takes 1024 input channel. I wonder how it is possible? i didn't really get how this 512 output channel is fed into 1024 of the input channel of the next nn.Seqential.

```
self.face_decoder_blocks = nn.ModuleList([
        nn.Sequential(Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0),),   #1, 1

        nn.Sequential(Conv2dTranspose(1024, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0), # 3,3
        Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, residual=True),),

        nn.Sequential(Conv2dTranspose(1024, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),
        Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, residual=True),
        Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, residual=True),)]
```

and inside-forward function,

```
x = face_sequences
for f in self.face_encoder_blocks:
   x = f(x)
```

My Main question is stated above, please help me to understand this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure they are used in the model in the same order they're listed in the ModuleList?

Comment: Inside, forward function, they have for loop, that I have mentioned above. I think it will take the list in order.

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you sure this is what the code is executing? Have you tried it? Is this from a public github that you could share?

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. here is the link to the repo: there you can see underclass wav2lip you will find self.face_decoder_block, you can find the above code. https://github.com/Rudrabha/Wav2Lip/blob/master/models/wav2lip.py

Comment: Does anyone know How it has been done?